# After cloning the GitHub repository & installing npm through command line gives following error

Tags: git, github, npm, npm-install

After cloning the GitHub repository & installing npm through command line gives following error

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\Projects\React_Basics\package.json'
```

[image: See the screenshot of error]

Comment: Check react basic folder, it doesn't contains package.json file which is required by npm

Comment: I have checked it but it has package.json file. Also it has package-lock.json file

Answer (score 1):

I think it's related to NPM changed installation behavior.

You can resolve that issue by following methods:

- Ensure dependencies described correctly in `package.json`
- Just type `npm install` and hit Enter.
- If same issue exists, type `npm cache clean` and hit Enter
- type `npm install -g npm` and hit Enter.
- Retry `npm install`.

If issue not resolved even tried these methods, Please reply with your Node.js version, NPM version, Operating System, and package.json which is using.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not changed your directory to where the repository is stored in your local computer.
Try cd 'directory name' and then npm install